# Invalid setting in Excel key of the Engines section of the Windows Registry

Tags: c#, csv, oledb

I have a C# program that imports data from a csv file and puts the data into a SQLServerCE database table (on the local C-drive).  The program works on many users' machines, but a few users keep getting the error:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Invalid setting in Excel key of the Engines section of the Windows Registry. at
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection) at
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) at
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) at
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) at
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
```

**Here is the C# code:**

```
string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathToFile + ";Extended Properties=Text;";
string sqlCmd = "SELECT * FROM [" + filenameOnly + "]";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
{
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlCmd, conn);
  using (OleDbDataAdapter dadapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
  {
     conn.Open();
     dadapt.TableMappings.Add("Table", dataSourceAlias);
     dadapt.Fill(ds);
     conn.Close();
  }
}
```

**I've tried several things already:**

1. verified HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4\Engines\Text has
   "CSVDelimited" for the Format Key
2. verified the users have the most recent release of Jet4.0 (Msjet40.dll version 4.0.9511.0 Win dows XP SP3 and Security Bulletin MS08-028 )
3. verified HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Text does not have an extension that is more than 4 characters long

But, after all this, the users still can't import the csv file data because "Invalid setting in Excel key of the Engines section of the Windows Registry"

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: Have you seen this yet:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290068?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @DonBoitnott - thanks for the suggestion.  I've tried it but it hasn't fixed it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - thank you for updating the title.  I apologize for any inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.....
the Registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4\Engines\Text item UseZeroMaxScanAs was set to "0".... it needed to be changed to "One" for it to work properly.

Thank you for all of the suggestions.